# UV Editing - how to select one face from the rest

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a wooden plank which when unwrapped shows each face on my selected material however I need to orient one of the faces so that the grain (in the image) goes in the correct direction. When I select each 'corner' vertice for the particular face and then attempt to move it to a new position it is still attached to the original adjacent face(s). I have tried double selecting (double LMB) on the vertices which have a common 'border' with no improvement.     What is the correct method to select a single 'face' for re-orientation?         Refer image below where I need to move the 'face' highlited and re-orient it to match the grain of the timber ie 90 degrees (using A R 9 0)

[image]

Comment: Hi :). In top left corner of UV editor choose between vertex/edge/face select. With face selection - click the face and rotate.

Comment: That won't be enough, if _UV Sync Selection_ is disabled, the face will stay attached to the other adjacent faces and drag their vertices to the new position. To avoid this, enable _UV Sync Selection_, the button with two opposing arrows left to the _Vertex/EdgeFace Select_ buttons. At least this happens if he keeps all faces in _Edit Mode_ selected to see the complete UV map.

Comment: @Gordon True, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Thanks guys.I wasn't exactly sure what Gordon advised but I unselected UV Synch Selection and then selected 'face selection mode' (3rd icon to the right) and that enabled me to grab the 'face' and move it away, turn it to horizontal and move it to where I wanted. Does it matter if I end up with the positions of each 'face' in the UV editor separate from each other ie not adjacent.? Also does it matter if I use the CTRL key held during moving of those faces to obtain a finer movement?